# How to give position on jquery popup

Tags: jquery

On dialog position i am giving syntax on given format to place my dialog but it is wrong

```
 $(".openDialogs").live("click", function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $("<div></div>")
                .addClass("dialog")
                .attr("id", $(this)
                .attr("data-dialog-id"))
                .appendTo("body")
                .dialog({
                    position:[10,100],
                    resizable: false,
                    minWidth:250,
                    maxWidth: 350,
                    title: $(this).attr("data-dialog-title"),
                    close: function () { $(this).remove() },
                    modal: true
                })
                .load(this.href);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `.dialog()` code is correct and its position is correct.  check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/373/), may correct your code as below.

```
.attr("id", $(this))
.attr("data-dialog-id")
```